# Issues of saving a matrix to a csv file

Tags: java, eclipse, csv

I am trying to save an integer matrix to the csv file. My code is listed as follows.

```
try
    {
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("test.csv");          
         for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
         {
            for (int j=0; j<(column-1); j++)
             {
                 writer.append(Matrix[i][j]);
                 writer.append(',');
             }
               writer.append(Matrix[i][j]);
               writer.append('\n');
               writer.flush();
         }
         writer.close();
      }        
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, the  Eclipse gives the following error message:

> method append(CharSequence) in the type Writer is not 
>    applicable for the arguments (int)

How to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Style comment - do not name instance variables (Matrix) with initial leading capital.  That is how you should be naming classes instead.

Comment: Additionally, there are CSV utilities out there to help you avoid writing this kind of code.  See ostermillerutils for instance (http://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your calls to `append(Matrix[i][j])` to `append(String.valueOf(Matrix[i][j])` or `append("" + Matrix[i][j])`.  The problem (as the error message points out) is that you are attempting to append an integer, but the append method only take a CharSequence (i.e. a String).  Both of the solutions I present coerce the integer/numeric type to a String.

Answer (score 1):

As @I82Much mentioned, and an alternative is to use [write](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write%28int%29) (for `,`, to avoid the creation of string). Also, you use `j` outside the for loop, so you need to declare it outside as well:

```
int j;
for (j=0; j<(column-1); j++)
{
    writer.append(Matrix[i][j]);
    writer.append(',');
}
writer.append(Matrix[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, another way to do it is use

```
writer.append(Integer.toString(Matrix[i][j]));
```

Also as @MByD said you have to declare `j` outside the loop if you're using it outside the loop.